# Calling two functions in the OnClientClick event

Tags: asp.net

I want to check two conditions in the `OnClientClick` event of an asp.net button control. I tried this but it is only checking the first function.

```
OnClientClick="javascript:shouldSubmit=true; return checkFunction1(); return checkFunction2();
```

What is the correct way  do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing any more about the two functions, I'd suggest something along the following lines:

```
... OnClientClick="return check();" ...

function check(){
  // Call function1 and save the return value.
  var success1 = checkFunction1();
  // Call function2 and save the return value.
  var success2 = checkFunction2();

  // Return the logical combination of the two values:
  // If both are true, return true, otherwise return false.
  return success1 && success2;
}
```

Depending on the checks you are doing, you might want to be a bit more clever about it - so if `checkFunction1` returns false, then don't bother even running `checkFunction2`:

```
function check(){
  if (checkFunction1()){
    // function1 returned true, continuing:
    if (checkFunction2()){
      // function2 returned true, allow click to continue:
      return true;
    }
  }

  // One or more returned false:
  return false; 
}
```

If you really want to inline it all, you could do:

```
OnClientClick="javascript:shouldSubmit=true; return checkFunction1() && checkFunction2();
```

Comment: Just wanted to note that ASP.NET renders `&&` inside OnClientClick as `&amp;&amp;` so the `javascript:` prefix is really important

Answer (score 0):

When you return, javascript stops executing the next statement, so you better put the "checkFunction2()" inside "checkFunction1()"

Answer (score 0):

I should do it like this:

```
... OnClientClick="return check();" ...

function check(){
   checkFunction1();
   checkFunction2();
}
```

Comment: this is not working good.after executing checkFunction1() it is executing its serverside function then it is going for function2

Comment: You're swallowing the return values from the two checkFunctions.